# Does async/await vs blocking in a linear program influence performance of other applications?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have a Console application that is making i.e. Web Requests and database calls in a linear manner and then closes. So in theory there is not much multithreading going on.

Because it interacts with IronPython it doesn't really support async/await very well.

If I make this whole application *blocking* instead of async/await - does this have any influence in resource consumption to **other applications running on the same server** (Azure App Service)?

Comment: If you have CPU bound work (ray-tracing, doing nuclear simulations, etc.), then farming it out to as many threads as you have virtual cores on the machine will make your app more efficient and will slow down other users/apps. If you have I/O bound work, and you have no "keep the UI responsive" requirements and no other responsibilities (like making other web users happy), just do what works and is easiest to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe so.

Either your main thread is blocked, then released, then blocked and so on, which produces practically zero impact on the system,

or, your thread pool picks one thread, releases it, then another, releases again, then may be another again, and so on, all from the pool, which again, produces zero impact.

Comment: This is assuming all of the work being done is CPU bound work done by a thread pool thread.  The question is no tasking about that situation though, it *specifically* indicated that the work is *not* that type of work in fact.

Comment: @Servy well, "i.e. database requests and web requests" are not CPU bound per se.

Comment: Exactly, which is why this answer is just strictly wrong.